# Match characters after a Keyword in a line that starts with SUM

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the characters after a certain keyword (in this case it's FOR) when the line starts with SUM.

Example:

```
SUM A+B+C TO var FOR D->E=F
```

Expected Result:

```
D->E=F
```

Any help/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the regex:
    `^SUM.*?FOR(.*)`

If it matches then the first group will contain the string after the 'FOR'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your regex:

```
/SUM(.*?)FOR (.*)/
```

and use the value of $2 variable